# select sql row using pdo with where statement

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, pdo

This is my first time to try PDO and still learning it. I am more familiar in using mysql or mysqli in developing php system.

After deep searching and searching I still can't seem to understand how to query using PDO

In my code I used mysqli inside a function to be called in index.php

```
function getUsery(){
    $ip = getIPAddress();
    $query = mysqli_query("select userID from tblUsers where logged='1'  AND ip='$ip'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);  
    $emp = $row['userID'];
    $logged = $row['logged'];
    $userlvl = $row['userLevel'];
    $_SESSION['logged'] = $logged;
    $_SESSION['userLevel'] = $userlvl;
    return $emp;
}
```

I don't really know how to select sql query using PDO with 'where' statement. Most of what I found is using array with no 'where' statement

How can I select the userID where logged is equal to '1' and ip is equal to the computer's ip address and return and display the result to the index.php

Comment: Ouch! SQL injection anyone?

Comment: do you know how to declare database connection in PDO?

Comment: @david yes, just learned it through web searching (self learning) I already declared database connection using PDO

Comment: Take a looky here, it's probably the best tutorial on using PDO which lots of examples (like `where`): https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: @Loek thanks will read this. hope i will understand this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you know how to connect database using PDO, here is how to select SQL with PDO.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("select userID from tblUsers where logged = '1' AND ip = :ip");
$stmt->execute(array('ip' => $ip));
$listArray = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Notice the `:ip` at the end of `SELECT`. If you don't use `?` as a parameters, the prefix `:` is mandatory and the word after that should be the same as the key in the execute function.

**EDIT**

In case that the above code is inside the function and `$db` is outside the function, declare `$db` as global variable inside the function.

Comment: thank you. do you know if i can use this inside a function?

Comment: yes, of course. If your database connection is set outside of function, you can use the variable that have PDO connection by declaring it as global in your function.

Answer (score 1):

There's SQL statement with WHERE in PDO

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users 
WHERE userID = ?";
$result = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$result->execute([$id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is imo one of best guides on PDO and how to use it:
https://phpdelusions.net/pdo
WHERE is a part of query and queries in PDO are not much different from pure *sql queries, just there is going on a bit filtering on execution. Read the guide carefully and you will be able to execute any query you need to.